# Printed NaN value after .map operator

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, response

To understand the idea of rxjs operators such as map and tap, I decided to make a simple example. In this example in my firebase database I stored an array that includes these `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` numbers. I can fetch them and push them via tap method

```
 myNumbers:number[]=[];
  fetchNumbers() {
        return this.http
          .get<number>('https://deneme-65e26.firebaseio.com/deneme.json')
              .pipe(
                 tap(myNumbers=> {
                  this.myNumbers.push(myNumbers);
                }) 
              )}
```

in my component also I'm listening this method with `.subscribe()` and printing the response on my console

```
 onFetch() {
    this.dataService.fetchNumbers().subscribe(
      response=>
      {
        console.log(response);
      }
    ); 
  }
```

Up to this point there's no problem. When I want to get this response multiplied by 10, the `.map()` method should help me as I know. But it returns me `NaN` on the console. Where's my mistake? Here's how I tried using the `.map()` method.

```
 fetchNumbers() {
        return this.http
          .get<number>('https://deneme-65e26.firebaseio.com/deneme.json')
              .pipe(
                 map(myNumbers=>
                  {return 10*myNumbers;
                  })
              )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the (slightly more comprehensible) [documentation of the map operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) you will see that the `map`operator is called every time your source observable emits.

This might be where your confusion comes from as it makes the operator different from the native `Array.map` function. The function passed to `Array.map` is called on **every element** of the array while the `map` operator is called on **every emitted value** of your observable.

In your case your emitted value is of type `Array` and so your code is trying to execute

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] * 10
```

which will naturally evaluate to `NaN`.

You can fix your code by now making sure you are calling the `Array.map` function on the emitted array like so:

```
.pipe(
      map((myNumbers: number[]) => myNumbers.map((value: number) => value*10))
 )
```